# Mockjax not intercepting async form submission

Tags: javascript, ajax, testing, qunit, mockjax

I'm using qUnit and mockjax to try and handle a simple async form submission but for some reason, the async POST seems to pass through mockjax.

```
test 'RuleModal closes the modal on a successful form submission event', ->
  $.mockjax
    dataType: 'json'
    url: '/url'
    type: 'post'
    responseText:
      status: 'success'

  $dom = $('<div class="show-modal"><form action="/url" method="post"></form></div>')
  $form = $dom.find('form')
  modal = new RuleModal($dom)

  $form.submit()

  equal $($dom).hasClass('show-modal'), false, 'closes the modal after form submission'
```

and the implementation

```
_bindSubmit: ->
  modal = this

  @$modal.find('form').on 'submit', (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()

    $.ajax
      dataType: 'json'
      url: @action
      type: @method
      data: $(this).serialize()
      success: (data, status, xhr) ->
        modal.close()
      error: (xhr, status, error) ->
        alert 'Something went wrong: ' + error
```

I tried hardcoding the implementation to match the test exactly but that still didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that because you do the form submit and then immediately do your assertion that you are running into a race condition. The `$form.submit()` call is going to execute and still be running when your `equal ...` line runs. Even though you have mocked out the ajax call, it is still asynchronous. Unfortunately, the browser native events (like `submit`) do not have any kind of callback when they finish, so you may just need a `setTimeout()` around the assertion:

```
$form.submit();

setTimeout(function() {
    equal($($dom).hasClass('show-modal'), false, 'closes the modal after form submission');
}, 100);  // I think the default in Mockjax is 50ms
```

That or you could try doing this in an event handler, but that could produce a race condition as well, I think.